# How to read the first element of a text file and if it matches it, to read the rest of the line?

Tags: java, text

I'm trying to check if the text file contains "Circle" or "Square" and if so to read the rest of the line. I have tried using `scan.next()=="Circle"` but that doesn't seem to work.
EDIT: The numbers refer to x and y coordinates which will be implemented into an instance of a class. In this case, Square and Circle.

**Text File:**

```
Circle 50 60 40 50 50
Square 250 260 45 -50 -50
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: You should start with learning about the fundamental concepts of Java; for example: instead of worrying about how to read a file ... step back and learn about the proper ways to compare objects in Java.

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading from a text file try using a `BufferedReader` and then using readLine and then using .equals() instead of `==`

An example:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myTextFile));
String lineOne = reader.readLine();
if(lineOne.equals("circle"))
{
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, the “==” operator is used to compare 2 objects. It checks to see if the objects refer to the same place in memory. In other words, it checks to see if the 2 object names are basically references to the same memory location.
So you should make use of equals. But in your case, if a line starts with circle or square you have to read the line from the given file.

Can you use the following condition and check if it works with scanner itself?

```
    String line = sc.next();
    if (line.startsWith("Circle") || line.startsWith("Square")){
        //Your logic
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileReader {

    public FileReader() {
        Scanner scanner;
        List<String> list;
        try {
            list = new ArrayList<>();
            scanner = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String s = scanner.nextLine();
                if (!s.startsWith("Circle") && !s.startsWith("Square")) {
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println(s);
                list.add(s);
            }
            scanner.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FileReader();

    }
```

The file is called file.txt:

```
Circle 50 60 40 50 50
Square 250 260 45 -50 -50
False 50 60 40 50 50
```

If you compare Strings, always use `equals` not `==`. Check [this](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/java-whats-the-difference-between-equals-and/) out